# Selenium w/Python3 class_status = like.get_attribute("class") AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_attribute' facing this issue

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Selenium w/Python3 class_status = like.get_attribute("class") AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_attribute' facing this issue
I am facing this issue when I call the first function is called but the number 2 function is not working

```
class Like():
  def __init__(self,video_xpath,like_refiq):
    self.video_xpath = video_xpath
    self.like_refiq=like_refiq
    # self.dislike=dislike
  def like_dislike(self):
    like =self.video_xpath
    time.sleep(5)
    # count = like.text
    class_status = like.get_attribute("class")
    if class_status == "selected":
      like.click()
      time.sleep(3)
      # alredy_like_cls_status = like.get_attribute("class")
      alredy_count = like.text
      return print(f"creation un{alredy_count} {self.like_refiq} count")
    elif class_status == "":
      like.click()
      time.sleep(3)
      # non_like_cls_status = like.get_attribute("class")
      non_count = like.text
      return print(f"creation {non_count} {self.like_refiq} count")
    else:
      assert False

class Refiq(Like):
  pass
```

```
like_path=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//w-creation-detail-popup//li[1]//a[1]")
        Like_dislike=Like(video_xpath=like_path,like_refiq="like")
        Like_dislike.like_dislike()
        # like dislike function call
        refq_unfrefiq=Refiq(video_xpath="//w-creation-detail-popup//li[2]//a[1]",like_refiq="refiq")
        refq_unfrefiq.like_dislike()
```

Comment: You should check a different attribute. Add html code

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned the `like` variable a string by `like =self.video_xpath`.
So, it's correct, `click` is a sting and you can't apply `.get_attribute("class")` on string object.
`click` is not a webelement object.